# Complex Relations

Tags: relations

I've got a pretty complex relatedTo situation and I can't figure out if it's possible in Craft.

Admin users have a field called "Admin Location" which is a Category field type, and may have more than one Category selected.

Regular users have a Matrix field called "Property Applications" which contains a sub-field of "Property" which is an Entry type. That Entry itself has a "Property Location" field - which is a Category field type with the same source categories as the Admin Location field.

For a given admin user, who has their Admin Location field set to one or more locations, I want to list all Users who have a Property in that same location.

This involves going through a Matrix, to an Entry, and then using the Entry's Category field.

I had tried this, but I am not getting results that I should if it were working as I wanted

```
{% set adminLocation = currentUser.adminLocation %}
{% set users = craft.users.relatedTo({
    element: adminLocation,
    field: 'propertyApplications.property.propertyLocation'
}) %}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Your `adminLocation` is an object of type `ElementCriteriaModel` not an element. You need to do `currentUser.adminLocation.ids()` to fetch the elements. Tell me of it works then... If not remove the field variable

Comment: It does not, and I can't just remove the field variable as it's important to the relation - it need to be related from that Matrix field's Entry field. 

I think the issue is I'm not looking for a relation on a field in the Matrix itself, but on a field from the Entry that's referenced in the Matrix.

Comment: Ahh yes of course.. sry I forgot about that. You can't revert search those fields like you are going to do it. You'll need php or a really messy twig solution for it because your countries are not related to the user but to the matrix block. You can see a  good example here https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/23117/how-to-get-all-images-from-entries-including-matrix-field a user wants exactly the same like you, just with assets and not with categories

Comment: That's unfortunately what I was worried was the case. I'm currently trying to write a plugin that uses the onBeforeSaveUser event to populate a new field on the Matrix which is an Entry type, with the same data as I need. It's not going so well! :/ Thanks though.

Comment: It's actually not that complicated you just have to understand Crafts database and it's relations but in order to help you we'll need your exact field layout in a clear way. Yii's query builder is really awesome, so you can create all relations by your own

Comment: ![Matrix Field Details](https://dev1.viewcreative.co.uk/example.png)

I'm trying to get the Property Location you can see there populated with the same content as is found in the Property Applied For's entry's own "Property Location" field - purely so I can do the relatedTo thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72774/discussion-between-matt-wilcox-and-robin-schambach).